# Appian "Only Show when" Expression: when date value is not null

Tags: excel, date, null, appian

I'm using Appian to create a interface form. I'm making the form dynamic. There's a textbox that needs to only appear when certain variables are true. Appian has a nice feature for that, which allows you to add an expression to an "only show when" function.

It currently holds the expression:

```
edate(today(), -804) >= ri!GeboorteDatum
```

ri!geboortedatum is the variable on the form

I need to add another expression that says: only show when date value is not null. I tried everything but can't get it to work. anyone got a solution? The programming language seems to be simular to excel.

Maybe something like

```
edate(today(), -804) >= ri!GeboorteDatum & isnull(ri!Geboortedatum)
```

Answer (score 2):

Answer is `if(isnull(ri!GeboorteDatum), false, edate(today(), -804) >= ri!GeboorteDatum)`